# Creating a Qt widget belonging to another widget made with Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a label in my mainwindow.cpp

```
lblmyLabel = new QLabel(this);
```

What do I put in place of "this" in order to have it show up in a layout that I created with the Qt designer?

I know this is a silly question but a simple answer would open a lot of doors for me as far as understanding how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can try the following.

First you shall add a `QWidget` where you want your `QLabel` to be displayed in the widget what you created in the Designer. And after that try the following lines:

```
void setMainWidget( QWidget* aParent, QWidget* aChild, const int aMargin = 0 )
{
    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout( aParent );
    layout->addWidget( aChild );
    layout->setMargin( aMargin );
    aParent->setLayout( layout );
}
```

In your case:

```
myLabel = new QLabel( ui->widget );
setMainWidget( ui->widget, myLabel );
```

It is useful for more complex custom widgets.

Comment: That will do it! thank you my friend! When it lets me select an answer I will do so!